# Issues Sending Expo AV Recorder to API (Not Working Only on Android)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, openai-api

I want to create a React Native application that records audio and sends it to the OpenAI API so that I can obtain a transcription. It works on iOS devices but not on Android devices (I have tried using many different devices). Is there anyone who can help me?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button ,ScrollView,TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';


export default function RecordingHome({navigation}) {
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState();
  const [lastRecording, setLastRecording] = useState();
  const [transcriptions,setTranscriptions] = useState(null)
  const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([])

  async function startRecording() {

    try {

      const perm = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (perm.status === "granted") {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          allowsRecordingIOS: true,
          playsInSilentModeIOS: true
        });
        console.log("device"+Platform.OS)

        

        const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync({...Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY,
          android: {
            extension: '.wav',
            outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4,
            audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC,
            sampleRate: 44100,
            numberOfChannels: 2,
            bitRate: 128000,
        },
          ios: {
              extension: '.wav',
              sampleRate: 44100,
              numberOfChannels: 2,
              bitRate: 128000,
          },
          
        });


        setRecording(recording);

      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("catch error "+err)
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    if (recording) {
    setRecording(undefined);

    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    const { sound, status } = await recording.createNewLoadedSoundAsync();
    setLastRecording({
      sound: sound,
      duration: getDurationFormatted(status.durationMillis),
      file: recording.getURI()
    });
    
  } else {
    console.warn("Recording is not defined");
  }
  
  }

  function getDurationFormatted(milliseconds) {
    const minutes = milliseconds / 1000 / 60;
    const seconds = Math.round((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60);
    return seconds < 10 ? `${Math.floor(minutes)}:0${seconds}` : `${Math.floor(minutes)}:${seconds}`
  }

  function clearLastRecording() {
    setLastRecording(null);
  }


  const sendRecordingToServer = async () => {
    
    if (lastRecording) {
      console.log("recording to server: "+lastRecording.file)
        try{
            const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('model', 'whisper-1');
    const file = {
      uri: "file:"+lastRecording.file.replace("file://", ""),
      name: lastRecording.file.split("/").pop(),
      type: "audio/vnd.wave",
    };
    console.log("File Object:", file);

    formData.append('file', file );
    formData.append('language', 'en');
    formData.append(
      'prompt',
      'make a trascription'
    );
    formData.append('response_format', 'json');


    const response = await  fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', {
        method: 'POST',

        headers: {          
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
      },);        
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();       
        if (jsonResponse && jsonResponse.text) {
          console.log("response "+Platform.OS +": "+JSON.stringify(jsonResponse))
          setTranscriptions(jsonResponse.text)
          console.log('transcription'+transcriptions)
        }
        else{
          console.log("something is wrong")
        }
        //console.log("response "+Platform.OS +": "+transcriptions)
        
        }catch (error) {            
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }    
    }
    else{
        console.log('error lastrecord')
    }
  };


  useEffect(()=>{
    sendRecordingToServer();
  },[lastRecording])

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(transcriptions!==null && transcriptions!=="")//sometinghs else
    {
      sendTextToServer();      
    }
  },[transcriptions])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!recording)
    startRecording();
    return async () => {
      if (recording) {
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
      }
    };
  }, [recording]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(tasks && tasks.length > 0){
      console.log("task before handfle "+tasks)
      handleTransacriptionInJson(tasks)
    }
  },[tasks])



  const handleTransacriptionInJson = (tasks)=>{
    console.log("in handle tasks "+ tasks)
    if(tasks && tasks.length > 0)
    navigation.navigate('TranscriptionInJson',tasks)
  }
  

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title={"Stop Recording"} onPress={stopRecording} />
        {lastRecording && (
          <>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <Text style={styles.fill}>
                Last Recording | {lastRecording.duration}
              </Text>
              <Button
                onPress={() => lastRecording.sound.replayAsync()}
                title="Play"
              ></Button>
            </View>            
          </>
        )}        
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

The error that I encounter is:

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid file format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']","type":"invalid_request_error","param":null,"code":null}}
```

This project is for learning in React Native, so feel free to provide any critiques. I'm open to feedback as it helps me learn more about this framework.